# embed never gets field added in .then()

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, discord.js

I have a function generateEmbed that fetches a user based on an id, then makes an embed field to add to the embed. This currently does not actually add a field to the embed.

The function in question:

```
function generateEmbed(startIndex, listOfPrompts, event) {
  const currentPage = listOfPrompts.slice(startIndex, startIndex + pageLength);

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Writing prompts ${startIndex + 1}-${startIndex + currentPage.length} out of ${listOfPrompts.length}`);

  currentPage.forEach(prompt => {
    event.client.users.fetch(prompt.author).then(promptAuthor => {
      const field2 = `${promptAuthor.username}#${promptAuthor.discriminator}`;

      embed.addField(prompt.name, field2);
    });
  });

  return embed;
}
```

Just to make sure I have it all covered, making it log prompt.name and field2 to console shows it finds the right text, but it does not get added. From later testing, I have found that this is due to asynchronous calls to fetch, as removing the fetch command and using synchronously declared text in field2 works.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

to

```
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

Comment: i am new to JS but i think this should fix it

Comment: This would not change anything. I can add to the embed while it is a constant. The problem is with asynchronous calls that don't finish in time.